# how to reformat date in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, date, datetime

i have an database of order and it order date
then it order date will be uploaded to database like this (3-3-2020)

then in my shop application, i call the database using JSON, and i want to convert 3-3-2020 to Tuesday, March, 2020

i try this solution

```
    pertemuan = getIntent().getStringExtra("pertemuan");

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
    String tanggal = format.format(pertemuan);

    pertemuanview.setText(tanggal);
```

but it give me this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.appguru/com.app.appguru.Detail_Pesanan}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

then how to reformat the date?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Are you storing the date as text (`char` datatype) in your database? Given that your database engine has a `date` datatype, it’s recommended that you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong object in `format.format` it suppose to be `Date` object and you are passing `String` thats why it is throwing `IllegalArgumentException`.
First you need to convert your string date to date object and pass to formatter like below.

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat currentDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = currentDateformat.parse("3-3-2020");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String tanggal = format.format(date);
```

Hope this will help you.